# How to stop a callback?

Tags: javascript, callback, html5-canvas

I have the following lines from a canvas sprite animation from Git.

I am just wondering how can I stop the animations once it ends the sprite.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) { // shim
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

function animate() { // Animation loop that draws the canvas
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
  spriteMap.draw(context, 100, 100); // Draw the sprite
  requestAnimFrame(animate); // Run the animation loop
}
```

https://github.com/IceCreamYou/Canvas-Sprite-Animations

Comment: Just wrap `requestAnimFrame(animate);` inside an `if` statement!

Comment: Are you looking for [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)?

Comment: And what shall I say in that if statement? @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: Well what did you said in the second line of the description of the question (_once it ends the sprite_)! And only you knows how!

Comment: Sounds like you copied code and don't know how it is meant to be used. I'd suggest reading that page you linked to, and the documentation linked to from it, and do some more research into how sprite animation works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cancelAnimationFrame()` together with the request-id returned by `requestAnimationFrame()`:

```
var reqId;

function animate() {
  // ...
  reqId = requestAnimFrame(animate); // returns request ID
}
```

Then to stop:

```
cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);
```

If you depend on the polyfill you will also have to include the [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) for `cancelAnimationFrame()`:

```
if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
    clearTimeout(id);
  };
```